# Moving Custom CLI commands to another file

Tags: flask

I have a few custom cli commands for a flask app I'm writing. I'm following the instructions here:

[Command Line Interface](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/)

The problem is I do not want to put them all in my app.py file, it will get overbloated. What I would like to do is have my project structure:

```
project
  |_ app.py
  |_ cli.py
```

I thought about using a blueprint, but I get "Blueprint has no attribute 'cli'"

This is what I tried:

```
cli = Blueprint('cli', __name__)  # I knew this would not work but I had to try

@cli.cli.command()
@click.argument('name')
def create_user(name):
    print("hello")
```

Thanks

Comment: did you figure out through, what the reason was for your error because similar code works fine for me.

Comment: The above code worked just fine, I just wanted to move these to another file so I don't have a huge app.py file. Please see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

cli.py:

```
from flask import Flask
import click

def register_cli(app: Flask):
    @app.cli.command()
    @click.argument('name')
    def create_user(name):
        print("hello", name)
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from cli import register_cli

app = Flask(__name__)
register_cli(app)
```

It's common to create and configure (or just configure) `app` in [factory functions](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory).