# Where should I implement flask custom commands (cli)

Tags: python, flask, command-line-interface, python-click, flask-cli

Creating custom commands in flask needs access to the app, which is generally created in `app.py` like this:

```py
import click
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.cli.command("create-user")
@click.argument("name")
def create_user(name):
    ...
```

However, in order not to bloat my app.py, I want to put my custom commands in a separate file e.g. `commands.py`, but this doesn't work because the entrypoint to my project is `app.py`, so I'll have to import app in `commands.py`and import my commands in `app.py` which results in a circular import error.

How can I create custom commands in separate files ?

Comment: I am not sure, but you need probably `with app.app_context():`, check [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/appcontext/)

Comment: @Roman yes, but I need to import app first to be able to do `with app.app_context():`. So the same problem remains.

Comment: You can also check the response in an older and similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/54824126/606826 in short create a factory function and pass your app as an argument `def register_cli(app: Flask):`

Answer (score 32):

One way to achieve this would be using [blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#custom-commands)

I have tested it using Flask 1.1.1, so be sure to check the documentation of the correct version that you have.

Here is the general idea:

1. Create one or more Blueprints in a different file, let's say it's called commands.py
2. Then import the new blueprints and register them to your app

==> app.py <==

```py
from flask import Flask
from commands import usersbp

app = Flask(__name__)
# you MUST register the blueprint
app.register_blueprint(usersbp)
```

==> commands.py <==

```py
import click
from flask import Blueprint

usersbp = Blueprint('users', __name__)

@usersbp.cli.command('create')
@click.argument('name')
def create(name):
    """ Creates a user """
    print("Create user: {}".format(name))
```

Upon executing `flask users` you should get a response like the following:

```sh
flask users
Usage: flask users [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  create  Creates a user
```

Comment: Yes, it's documented as away to register custom commands: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#registering-commands-with-blueprints. However, is there a way to register custom commands without using Blueprints?

Comment: this is the best feasible solution

Comment: Just a note that a blueprint adds a command group by default, check the `cli_group` option in the docs if this is not what you want.

Comment: It is also working in Flask 2

Comment: The above solution works for Flask v2.2.2

Answer (score 7):

just import it in your app factory

```
dir tree

my_app
     L app.py
     L commands.py
```

commands.py

```py
@app.cli.command('resetdb')
def resetdb_command():
    """Here info that will be shown in flask --help"""
    pass
```

app.py

```py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from . import routes
        from . import commands  # <----- here

        return app
```

```sh
$ export FLASK_APP=my_app/app.py
$ flask resetdb
```

but there have to be better way ;) of which I am unaware right now

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me out of "ALL flask cli solution found over google search, including the flask cli documentation itself"

Comment: How are you importing `app` into commands.py?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using an app factory (you have a `create_app()` function), then there isn't even an `app` variable for you to import.

The best way to keep your code organized is to define the function somewhere else, and then register it when building the application instance.

E.g.

```
my_app/
 | main.py
 | app/
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | commands.py
```

**commands.py**

```
def foo():
   print("Running foo()")
```

****init**.py**

```
def create_app():
 app = Flask(__name__)
 ...
 from .commands import foo
 @app.cli.command('foo')
 def foo_command():
   foo()
 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

My practice:

├── app.py

├── commands.py

in app.py:

```py
from commands import register_commands

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ....

    register_commands(app)
    return app
```

in commands.py

```py
from sqlalchemyseeder import ResolvingSeeder
from app import db

def register_commands(app):
    @app.cli.command("seed_courses")
    def seed_courses():
        seeder = ResolvingSeeder(db.session)
        seeder.load_entities_from_json_file("app/db/seed/data.json")
        db.session.commit()
        db.session.close()

    @app.cli.command("command2")
    def another_command():
        print("another command")
```

run:

```py
flask seed_courses
flask command2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this layout:

**baseapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("CmdAttempt")
```

**app.py**

```
from .baseapp import app

def main():
    app.run(
        port=5522,
        load_dotenv=True,
        debug=True
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**commands.py**

```
import click

from .baseapp import app


@app.cli.command("create-super-user")
@click.argument("name")
def create_super_user(name):
    print("Now creating user", name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from .app import main
    main()
```

In the console where you run the commands first define the `FLASK_APP` to be `commands.py`, then run the commands that you define.

```
set FLASK_APP=commands.py
export FLASK_APP=commands.py
flask create-super-user me
```

You can either use a separate terminal for built-in commands or clear the `FLASK_APP` variable before issuing them. In Linux is even easier because you can do

```
FLASK_APP=commands.py flask create-super-user me
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in case you are not using app factory pattern, similar to @quester:

**app.py**

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

with app.app_context():
    # needed to make CLI commands work
    from commands import *
```

**commands.py**

```
from app import app

@app.cli.command()
def do_something():
    print('hello i am so nice I posted this even though I have 100 other things to do')
```

Comment: Is this working? I am getting circular dependency issue. `ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from partially initialized module 'app' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

**app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    import commands
    application = Flask(__name__)

    application.cli.add_command(commands.hello)
    return application


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run()
```

**commands.py:**

```
import click


@click.command("say_hello")
@click.argument("name")
def hello(name):
    """ Say hello to user """
    print(f"Hello {name}")
```