# flask command Error: No such command ["create_db"]

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, command-line-arguments, flask-cli

I want to run some commands from terminal with 'flask' command but it isn't working.

The Following is my project structure-

```
FlaskUserAuthentication
├── FlaskUserAuthentication
│   ├── API
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── db_models.py
│   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── Site
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── form_style.css
│   │   └── templates
│   │       └── Site
│   │           ├── base_layout.html
│   │           ├── index.html
│   │           ├── logout.html
│   │           ├── profile.html
│   │           ├── signin.html
│   │           └── signup.html
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── commands.py
├── run.py
└── venv
```

As the `flask run` command runs the app, I am sure that my environment variable  is set properly. However, when I try to use flask-cli-command like-

```
flask create_db
```

I get, `Error: No such command "create_db".`

The following is my `FlaskUserAuthentication/commands.py` file-

```
from FlaskUserAuthentication import app, db
from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.db_models import Group, Member, Project, Milestone

@app.cli.command('create_db')
def createDatabase():
    db.create_all()
    print('***** Datebase created ****')

#....some more commands
```

and the `FlaskUserAuthentication/__init__.py` module (where the Flask app instance is initiated)-

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'justasamplekey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.routes import api
from FlaskUserAuthentication.Site.routes import site

app.register_blueprint(api)
app.register_blueprint(site)
```

Comment: Check it - https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/#registering-commands-with-blueprints

Comment: I don't know why my question had been downvoted but this is not a duplicate question as I tried other solutions on stack and addressed that too. Anyways, I need help, so downvote or not, can anyone please direct me to the right direction as I am confused on what I have done wrong.

Comment: try the following `flask --help` It shows you all the commands registered under `flask cli`. Moreover, your `CLIGroup` should be executed in the `run.py` where I assume you are running the server.

Comment: flask --help didn't do much for me as it was only telling me how to execute a command and the three commands that was available but I needed to know the source of my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that the `command.py` module was not recognized by the app. The solution, I tried is to initiate a blueprint in the `commands` module and then in the `__init__.py` module where I initiated the `app` instance, I registered the corresponding Blueprint with it. So, the updated `commands.py`-

```
from FlaskUserAuthentication import db
from flask import Blueprint
from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.db_models import Group, Member, Project, Milestone

@cmd = Blueprint('db', __name__) #created a Blueprint for this module

@cmd.cli.command('create_db') #rather than generating the cli command with app,
def createDatabase():         # used the blueprint, cmd
    db.create_all()
    print('***** Datebase created ****')
```

and the updated `__init__.py` module,

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'justasamplekey'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from FlaskUserAuthentication.API.routes import api
from FlaskUserAuthentication.Site.routes import site
from FlaskUserAuthentication.commands import cmd

app.register_blueprint(api)
app.register_blueprint(site)
app.register_blueprint(cmd) # registered the command module as blueprint
```

Now set the environment variable and development server with (in the terminal) -

```
export FLASK_APP=FlaskUserAuthentication/__init__.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

After that use the flask command like-

```
flask db create_db
```

P.S.: now because of the Blueprint rather than `flask create_db`, the command will be

```
flask db create_db
```

I needed to realise the root of the issue and for that I thank the author of the post-

[Where should I implement flask custom commands (cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202736/where-should-i-implement-flask-custom-commands-cli)

and the author, @emont01 for his response to the post.

Comment: thanks for the mentioned 'Where should I implement flask custom commands (cli)' post, that was helpful!