# Splitting application.py file into seperate files

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have an issue, I have created a command in my project for creating the database, my issue is that I would like to move it and other simmilar things to seperate files, but if I try to import them from a different file I get an import error, could anyone help me resolve this issue, thank you.
This is my application.py file.

```
import flask

from database_website.extensions.database import db
from database_website.properties import navigation_bar


class Application(flask.Flask):
    def load_configuration(self):
        self.config.from_pyfile('configuration.py')

    def configure_database(self):
        from database_website.extensions.database import db

        db.init_app(app=self)

    def configure_login_manager(self):
        from database_website.extensions.auth import login_manager

        login_manager.init_app(app=self)

    def register_applications(self):
        from database_website.applications.core.urls import blueprint as core_blueprint
        from database_website.applications.users.urls import blueprint as users_blueprint
        from database_website.applications.products.urls import blueprint as products_blueprint

        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=users_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=products_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=core_blueprint)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        instance = Application(__name__)

        instance.load_configuration()
        instance.configure_database()
        instance.configure_login_manager()
        instance.register_applications()

        return instance


application = Application.create()


@application.cli.command()
def create_database():
    db.create_all()


def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


def sitemap():
    links = []
    for rule in application.url_map.iter_rules():
        # Filter out rules we can't navigate to in a browser
        # and rules that require parameters
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = flask.url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    return links


@application.context_processor
def inject_endpoints():
    return dict(endpoints=sitemap())


@application.context_processor
def inject_navigation():
    return dict(nav_bar=navigation_bar)


application.run()
```

And things I want to move would be the injects and the command.

My application.py file after editing and moving the command to a commands.py file.

```
mport flask

from flask_migrate import Migrate

from database_website.extensions.database import db
from database_website.properties import navigation_bar
from database_website.commands import create_database


class Application(flask.Flask):
    def create_migrations(self):
        migrate = Migrate(self, db)

    def load_configuration(self):
        self.config.from_pyfile('configuration.py')

    def configure_database(self):
        from database_website.extensions.database import db

        db.init_app(app=self)

    def configure_login_manager(self):
        from database_website.extensions.auth import login_manager

        login_manager.init_app(app=self)

    def register_applications(self):
        from database_website.applications.core.urls import blueprint as core_blueprint
        from database_website.applications.users.urls import blueprint as users_blueprint
        from database_website.applications.products.urls import blueprint as products_blueprint

        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=users_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=products_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=core_blueprint)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        instance = Application(__name__)

        instance.load_configuration()
        instance.configure_database()
        instance.configure_login_manager()
        instance.register_applications()
        instance.create_migrations()

        return instance


application = Application.create()


def has_no_empty_params(rule):
    defaults = rule.defaults if rule.defaults is not None else ()
    arguments = rule.arguments if rule.arguments is not None else ()
    return len(defaults) >= len(arguments)


def sitemap():
    links = []
    for rule in application.url_map.iter_rules():
        # Filter out rules we can't navigate to in a browser
        # and rules that require parameters
        if "GET" in rule.methods and has_no_empty_params(rule):
            url = flask.url_for(rule.endpoint, **(rule.defaults or {}))
            links.append((url, rule.endpoint))
    return links


@application.context_processor
def inject_endpoints():
    return dict(endpoints=sitemap())


@application.context_processor
def inject_navigation():
    return dict(nav_bar=navigation_bar)


application.run()
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ulman\PycharmProjects\database_website_optimised\source\database_website\application.py", line 7, in <module>
    from database_website.commands import create_database
  File "C:\Users\ulman\PycharmProjects\database_website_optimised\source\database_website\commands.py", line 1, in <module>
    from database_website.application import application
  File "C:\Users\ulman\PycharmProjects\database_website_optimised\source\database_website\application.py", line 7, in <module>
    from database_website.commands import create_database
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_database' from 'database_website.commands' (C:\Users\ulman\PycharmProjects\database_website_optimised\source\database_website\commands.py)
```

I moved the command over to a commands file and then imported it into the application file.

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

I haven't ran this myself but something like this *should* point you in the right direction. You should be able to register your commands blueprint just like the other blueprints you are already registering.

commands.py

```py
from flask import Blueprint

from database_website.extensions.database import db

blueprint = Blueprint('commands_blueprint', __name__)

@commands_blueprint.cli.command()
def create_database():
    db.create_all()
```

applications.py

```py
import flask

from database_website.extensions.database import db
from database_website.properties import navigation_bar

class Application(flask.Flask):
    ...
    def register_applications(self):
        from database_website.applications.core.urls import blueprint as core_blueprint
        from database_website.applications.users.urls import blueprint as users_blueprint
        from database_website.applications.products.urls import blueprint as products_blueprint
        from database_wensite.commands import blueprint as commands_blueprint

        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=users_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=products_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=core_blueprint)
        self.register_blueprint(blueprint=commands_blueprint)
    ...
```

You can use flask blueprints to help make your code more modular.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/

[Where should I implement flask custom commands (cli)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202736/where-should-i-implement-flask-custom-commands-cli)

Comment: I am using blueprints, but if I understand correctly, I can make the cli commands inside of the blueprint?(But the problem witht hat is tat in my case create-database command is not specific to a blueprint)

Comment: What does your code look like after you refactor and what error do you receive?

Comment: Will add to my edit,
edit: added to my original post, the way is janky, but without importing back in itwould not get read. You mentioned blueprints, so could I create a "Commands" blueprint for just commands? Or maybe there is a better way

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try to register your commands blueprint just like you might any other blueprint. NOTE: I don't know your project folder structure so be aware of imports

Comment: Thank you, it works on the commands part, but trying something like that on the injects made the injected objectbe undefined. I tried also using it as properties.nav_bar instead of just nav_bar in my template but that didnt seem to change anything. Maybe I am reffering to t incorrectly as when building the project, no errors were in sight

Comment: Upadte, found somewhere an answer to my question, turns out that istead of context_Processor I should use app_context_Processor

Comment: Not quite sure about the difference between the 2 but if you know it, I would be happy to know it too :)
Thanks again, for your help